# Setting google maps android version 2 to a specific area (zoomtospan equivalent in version 2? )

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2

In my monodroid application, I was using this code for setting google map bounds to a specific area.

```
mapView.Controller .ZoomToSpan (Math.Abs (maxLat - minLat), Math.Abs (maxLong - minLong));
mapView .Controller .AnimateTo (new GeoPoint ((maxLat + minLat) / 2, (maxLong + minLong) / 2));
```

but now, by updating to the version 2 can not find `zoomToSpan` method. What is the replacement mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Basim Sherif that his post get me idea for code, but on the google documentation for `iclude(latlng p0)` is said:

> it will consider extending the bounds both in the eastward and
>   westward directions (one of which may wrap around the world) and
>   choose the smaller of the two. In the case that both directions result
>   in a LatLngBounds of the same size, this will extend it in the
>   eastward direction.

I guess that if it extend bounds, so we can not have the exact area. Finally I used this code:

```
LatLngBounds bounds= new LatLngBounds (new LatLng (minLat ,minLong ),new LatLng (maxLat ,maxLong ));
mapView .MoveCamera (CameraUpdateFactory .NewLatLngBounds (bounds ,0));
```

I think it should be more efficient that other ways.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need,

first, get all LatLng points you want to zoom.

Lets take 3 LatLng points,

```
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder().include(point1)
                    .include(point2).include(point3).build();

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want to set an area with max lat,min lat,max lng and min lng. not a destination.